# File server giving CORS blocked error with vue-croppa

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This is my template code:

```
<croppa
  v-model="croppers[i]"
  placeholder="Select Image"
  initial-size="contain"
  :placeholder-font-size="25"
  :show-remove-button="false"
  :initial-image="initialImages[i]"
 ></croppa>
```

This my script to update initial image values for each cropper.

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    this.croppers[i].refresh()
    this.imageNames[i] = ''
    if (this.editProductFlag && (typeof this.productDetails.images !== 'undefined')) {
      if (typeof this.productDetails.images[i] !== 'undefined') {
        this.initialImages[i] = this.productDetails.images[i].image
        this.imageNames[i] = this.productDetails.images[i].description
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the error I am getting

```
Access to image at 'https://dev-pickl-img-static.pickl.pro/product_images/145/good_day5c3104b49e69b.png' from origin 'https://dev-app.pickl.pro' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have tried  tag also with `crossorigin="anonymous"` but still its not working. 
Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

No, CORS requests do not work as you can think.
You must check the documentation of your image provider and see if there is an option to enable CORS requests, otherwise will never be able to get the images from the frontend.